# Hartshorne P24 Lemma 4.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Lemma 4.1 says：let $X$ and $Y$ be two varieties, and let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two morphisms from $X$ to $Y$, and suppose there is a nonempty open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $\phi|_U = \psi|_U$, then $\phi = \psi$.

The proof assumes that $Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n$. But every projective variety can be covered by affine varieties(Corollary 2.3, P11). And proposition 4.3 says: every variety $Y$ has a base for the topology consisting of open affine subsets.

> My question is why we do not assume $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an
>   affine variety? What's the difference between Corollary 2.3 and proposition 4.3？(In proposition 4.3 assume $Y$ is projective)

Thank you vwry much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that $Y$ is covered by affine varieties does not mean $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ for some $n$. For example, this will never be true for $Y = \mathbb{P}^1$. On the other hand, every variety (by Hartshorne's Chapter I definition) sits inside of $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: I am confused. As proposition 4.3 says: every variety $Y$ has a base for the topology consisting of open affine subsets, and the 3rd line of the proof of Thm 4.4, the author assumes $Y$ is affine. When we should assume $Y$ is projective? When we should assume $Y$ is affine? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Saying $Y$ sits inside of $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n$ does _not_ mean that $Y$ is projective. $Y$ is projective precisely when it is a _closed_ subvariety. For example, $\mathbb{A}^n \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is not projective for $n > 0$. In the proof of Theorem 4.4 is local: to produce a rational map $X \rightarrow Y$, one needs to produce a morphism $U \rightarrow Y$ for some open subset of $X$. Since $X$ always has open subsets which are affine, we can just assume $U$ is affine.

Comment: When should you assume something is affine or projective? It all depends on the situation. When a property is local, one can usually get away with assuming the variety is affine. In Hartshorne Chapter I, a variety is assumed to be quasi-projective, so one can always assume its sitting in some $\mathbb{P}^n$ (by definition). This may not be helpful, depending on the proposition.

Comment: OK, thanks again.